Filling shape with labels
How can I fill a shape with labels?
The method I've tried is shown below:

This is the picture I want to make:


What is the result of your method?

Your method is correct, just make sure to adjust the Distance parameters for "Point Pattern Fill" until you get the density right:

Mine looks like this:

If you want the labels aligned with the flow of the river, that will take some extra work. You will have to divide the river into parts, calculate the orientation of each part, and set this value as the label "Rotation"
